# How to run multiple tasks simultaneously in the background of a IHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application that runs an `IHostedService` class as an background worker. Now I have two Tasks which run endlessly.

- **Task1**: Has an WebSocket connection that continuously receives data and stores it in the MSSQL database using EF Core
- **Task2**: Runs an endless loop which every 10 seconds runs over the Transactions that have been added to the database in Task1

Now my question is:
How do I let these two Tasks run simultaneously? Because right now **Task1** is blocking **Task2** from executing. Any help or suggestions on how to better solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

**IHostedService**

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task1();
    new Thread(Task2).Start();
}

public async Task Task1()
{
    using (var client = new StreamingWebSocketClient("wss://websocket.io"))
    {
       //Receive data from Websocket and store in MSSQLDB using EF Core
    }
}

private void Task2()
{
    using (_dbContext)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var transactions = _dbContext.Transactions.Where(t => t.To == null).ToList();

            foreach (Models.Transaction transaction in transactions)
            {
                //Do some work
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make two hosted services?

Comment: I have tried this, but when registering Task2 as a second hosted service in my Program.cs only Task1 would be running and Task2 would be blocked. So I didn't think it was possible. Would you say using two different hosted services is a better design?

Comment: Yes, I would. You're probably running into the [synchronous startup problem](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html), which [they're planning to fix in .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063#issuecomment-518913079).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `await` the first task until the second one runs:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var task1 = Task1();
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => Task2());
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

This gets slightly better when you do this:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var task1 = Task1();
    var task2 = Task2(cancellationToken);
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}


private async Task Task2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                var transactions = dbContext.Transactions.Where(t => t.To == null).ToList();
                foreach (Models.Transaction transaction in transactions)
                {
                    //Do some work
                }
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This made it work. What exactly is the use of giving an CancellationTokent to Task2 in your example?

Comment: @Bram - The `CancellationToken` is passed to `StartAsync` so it's there to let your service known when to stop. It should be used otherwise your process is hijacking the service.